What is the reason we Personify Kali?
Out of all four yugas, we only tend to personify Kali Yuga. Is there any particular reason behind this personification? It seems like, Kali Yuga is not governed by Devas but explicitly by some Asura. I was just curious about this little jargon.
Have a blissful day!

All the 4 yugas are personified. Mahabharata Sabhaparva describes personification of all 4 yugas attending Brahma's sabha. And Brahmavaivarta Purana states that the personification of Kaliyuga is one of the many sons of Brahma through Savitri. Modern day personification of Kaliyuga comes from British era pamphlets against cow slaughter drawing on the imagery of Kali attempting to slaughter a bovine couple in Janmejaya's visions in the Bhagavata Purana.

@অনু But I don't think that all four yugas are seen as "Manas Putras". If they are, then there is no need to personify either of them as they are already beings.
